# Extract 'salt' from mcrypt encrypted file

Tags: command, encryption, utilities

I have some [mcrypt(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mcrypt) encrypted files, doing `file` on them

```
ici$ file myfile.nc
myfile.nc: mcrypt 2.5 encrypted data, algorithm: rijndael-128, keysize: 32 bytes, mode: cbc
```

However, I'd like to extract the *salt* part (randomized during encryption) from the file. The *salt* is 20 bytes public data stored somewhere along the hash in the encrypted `.nc` file (I need the salt for a research project).

Is there a tool that does that, extract the *salt* part of an mcrypt encrypted file?

<sub>(note: there are many "mcrypt" results from a Google search. Here the question is about the mcrypt Linux command, not the PHP function)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it from the source, if that can interest anyone (doubt it)

The program reads the encrypted file header in `extra.c` around line 260, the *salt* was at position 36 (could vary a bit).